# Generic methods tutorial

Tags: java, generics, generic-list

In https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html, it is suggested to implement a method

```
public static double sumOfList(List<? extends Number> list) {
    double s = 0.0;
    for (Number n : list)
        s += n.doubleValue();
    return s;
}
```

and then to invoce it with

```
List<Integer> li = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
System.out.println("sum = " + sumOfList(li));
```

1. Why is it illegal to put `public static <T> double sumOfList(List<T extends Number> list)` ?
2. Is `public static <T extends Number> double sumOfList(List<T> list)` equivalent? If so, is it of less good style?
3. When using the aforementioned code, why is it illegal to write `System.out.println("sum = " + sumOfList<Integer>(li));`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Why is it illegal to put

Because that's just not the syntax.

`T` is a type variable, the bounds have to be specified where the type variable is declared (within the `<>` preceding the method return type), not where it is used (in the same way that the type of a variable has to be specified where it is declared, not where it is used, e.g. `String foo`, not `foo.<String>contains("a")`).

> 2. Is ... Equivalent?

Not quite.

The advantage of declaring a type variable and using that in the `List<T>` is that you can then declare variables of that type in the method.

For example:

```
T element = list.get(0);
list.set(0, element);
```

is not legal for a `List<? extends Number>`, but is for a `List<T>`.

You can also do things like using `T` in the return type of the method and/or other parameters.

But, if you don't need to do any of these things, you don't need a type variable, so don't declare one, just as you shouldn't declare variables you don't need.

> 3. When using the aforementioned code, why is it illegal to write

Because that's just not the syntax.

However, you can write:

```
System.out.println("sum = " + TheContainingClass.<Integer>sumOfList(li));
```

(Or e.g. `this.<Integer>sumOfList(...)`, if it were a non-static method)

i.e. the `<>` comes *before* the method name, and the method invocation needs to be qualified.

This `<Integer>` is sometimes called a ["type witness"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html), although that is not a term defined in the spec.